# In fabric, if two transactions in a block conflicted，what's the result

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In fabric, if two transactions in a block conflicted(eg, two users try to buy an asset almost at the same time) ,then these two will not be committed to the ledger, or just the last one will not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one is going to be successfully committed (the first one as ordered by the ordering service), as the version of the read set of the second transaction is not going to match the expected one.

Is very well explained in: https://medium.com/@arora.aditya520/chaincode-writing-best-practices-hyperledger-fabric-43d2adffbeec

Comment: So,if the block includes these two transaction, and the order delivers the block to the peers, the peers receive the block of  the two transaction, only one of the two will be remarked as valid. Is it right?@kekomal

Comment: That's right. Only the first one is validated and only the first one updates the state. The second one is registered in the block of that channel's chain, but it is not valid and it does not alter the state.

Comment: @kekomal Please see the question properly, he mentioned in `block` which is the wrong question. In block means the transactions are endorsed and committed by the committing peer's success/fail. Perhaps he should have asked the question `what if two transactions conflicted at the endorsement phase ?`

Comment: Once the endorsers have performed the endorsements and the client has verified that the endorsements match, the txs are sent to the orderer. The orderer orders txs in a block which is sent to commiters and is then, in the commiting phase, when the second tx is considered invalid by the committers. That tx does not alter the state, but the block is added anyway to the channel's chain. It can happen (endorsements can be performed by different endorsers and checked by different clients so that this situation cannot be detected before), so I find it a reasonable question (and response).

Comment: It is the classic `MVCC_READ_CONFLICT` error, which occurs at commit time, when the `block` has been already created by the ordering service and sent to the committers. The committers mark the second tx as invalid and add the `block` to the chain.

Comment: @kekomal,yes,these scenes are in consideration, and also if the two tx from different client are very close,even they have the same endorsers, i think it is possible these two tx packed in the same block, is this right?

Comment: Yes. Although the endorser, if the same, could detect this issue before, it does not, as it does not know by sure which transaction is going to be ordered before and what are doing other endorsers at the same time, so it is delegated to the commit phase.